# Why doesn't this Netbeans print from this code in the lower console

Tags: netbeans, java-8

This code will not produce any text output from the lower output console.  Am I missing a configuration setting or is the code wrong?

The code seems to be effective as the console will display that the build was successful in 0 seconds.

```
public class SpaceRemover {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String mostFamous = "Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer";
         char[] mfl = mostFamous.toCharArray();
         for (int dex = 0; dex < mfl.length; dex++) {
             char current = mfl[dex];
             if (current != ' ') {
                 System.out.print(current);
             } else {
                 System.out.print('.');
             }
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
}
```

Build was successful yet no text was printed.

Comment: Your code looks fine, and prints _"Rudolph.the.Red-Nosed.Reindeer"_ for me. Add `System.out.println("Start");` at the start of the `main()` method, and `System.out.println("End");` at the end of the `main()` method. What is shown in the Console window when you run with those changes?

Comment: Welcome @Christian, you are probably just hitting the Compile & Build, but not running the problem.

Comment: Look at this point: https://youtu.be/hshWDPWsZAU?t=189